# React native : create a popup that has multiple selection options

Tags: android, ios, popup, react-native, spinner

Does anyone know , how to create popup that has multiple selection, each selection want to have image, title , sub title?

I used modal picker- [link here](http://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-modal-picker). but, I cannot put image in picke

Comment: Show some effort, show what code you have and why that is not working. Stack Overflow is not a code factory, we help eachother out if you put effort into your work.

Comment: I used modal picker- https://github.com/d-a-n/react-native-modal-picker.  but, I cannot put image in picker

Answer (score 0):

Use custom dialog fragment. You can lay any kind of layout in dialog. Here is a good example.. https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-DialogFragment

Comment: I want idea to react native , not android